# Serilog udpsyslog Event Timestamp not showing milliseconds

Tags: serilog

I have `Serilog.Sinks.Syslog`, `Serilog V2`, `Serilog.Sinks.Console` and `Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching`, I am pushing logs to a Nagios LS server using `UDPSyslog` but what I have noticed is that unlike other loggers the `serilog udpsyslogger` is not adding milliseconds to the event timestamp as such I cannot trace properly.

My code is in C#.

```
  /*
   * Logging parameters to the syslog
   */
var log = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.With().WriteTo.UdpSyslog(outputTemplate: syslogMessageTemplate, host: syslogServer, port: syslogServerPort, appName: applicationName, format:SyslogFormat.RFC3164 , facility: Facility.User).CreateLogger();
```

Below is the picture.  Any idea what i am missing?

[image: Nagios Syslog server]

Comment: The timestamp format is often specified in the outputTemplate parameter. What is the value of syslogMessageTemplate here?